# Getting value from a table and add value from table 2 if excist

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL and im wondering if something like this is possible.

It's probably a super simple solution but i cant seem to solve it. I'm using an Oracle database.

`Employee_Table`:
employeeNr 
username
address
epost

`Computer_Table`:
employeeNr
ComputerNumber
ComputerUpdated

When I'm using

```
SELECT *
From Employee_Table,
     Computer_Table
WHERE Employee_Table.EmployeeNr = Computer_Table.EmployeeNr
  AND Employee_Table.username LIKE ('%SomeUsername%')
```

When I'm using this sqlstring I only get users with computers. I would like to get all users and the computers of those who has one. 

Now the million dollar question. What modifications do I need to make?

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN`.

In this case, you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee_Table e LEFT JOIN
     Computer_Table c
     ON c.EmployeeNr = c.EmployeeNr
WHERE e.username LIKE '%SomeUsername%';
```

When you use `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on the first table go on the `WHERE` clause.  Conditions on the second table go in the `ON` clause.

Comment: i got waht i wanted, now im struggling with adding 1 more table,
**Picture**
EmployeeNr
Picture

How can i add this to the SQL? Tried adding another LEFT JOIN but seems like its not working :(